# How to allow people to download .php files without the code being interpreted?

Tags: php, apache

I'm using apache2 and enabled a site that has no index.html file in its `<Directory>` directive, so an index of all the files is displayed instead of an html webpage.

I've included some .php files that I want to allow other people to download, however whenever I download a .php file from this page, it is already 'interpreted'.

For example if I save `hello.php` onto my desktop

```
<? php $var = 'hello world'; echo $var ?>
```

When I open up hello.php the code reads

`hello`

Is there any way I can allow people to download the code before it is interpreted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the server configuration you need a `.htaccess` with:

```
# for mod_php
php_value engine off
```

Or:

```
# for CGI setups
Options -ExecCGI
```

Or:

```
# for FastCGI this depends on the name of the handler script
RemoveHandler .php
#RemoveHandler php5-fastcgi .php
```

And sometimes even a brute-force method:

```
<FilesMatch "[.]php\d?$">
   ForceType text/php
   SetHandler default-handler
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Thanks, I added `php_value engine off` into one of my websites in sites-available inside the virtual host directive.

Comment: What if you want to generate your indexes using PHP? So the 'index.php' file needs to still execute?

Comment: @zeel: Add a `<Files index.php>` override section then for this exception.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the behavior at the server side.
For example, if the mod_php is disabled in Apache, and the MIME type of ".php" is configured as "application/binary", then accessing to "http://[server_ip]/hello.php" will cause the php file to be downloaded to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the php5 module from the apache configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use file_get_contents() to display the code contained within the file

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Answer (score 0):

You can try giving it a .phps extension, or a .txt extension. Some servers (if configured to do so) will allow the user to see a syntax highlighted version of the file if it has a .phps extension. Alternatively, you could use .htaccess to tell apache to not execute the file as php and force a download by telling it to send a application/octet-stream content type.